# Authenticating a user through a HTTP GET request in Angular 5 and Spring Sec 5

Tags: spring, angular, spring-security, http-headers, basic-authentication

I'm working on a Spring Boot 2 + Angular 5 project. For those of you who will recoginize it, this is super inspired from the [Spring Security and Angular tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) on the Spring Guides site.

I have a secure back-end using basic authentication.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class BasicApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BasicApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/resource")
    public Map<String, Object> home() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello Spring Security Boot 2 and Angular");
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/resource")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

When curl the `/resource` end-point, I **successfully** do

```
curl http://user:password@localhost:8080/resource
```

I would like to perform the exact same king of authentication with Angular. So I have implemented the following component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Hello WAT';
  greeting = { id: 'XXX', content: 'Hello World' };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'user:password'
      })
    };

    http
      .get<any>('http://localhost:8080/resource', httpOptions)
      .subscribe(resource => (this.greeting = resource));
  }
}
```

Here is what I have in the browser logs:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers authorization,content-type
```

And pretty logically, here is what the Spring Sec DEBUG logs are saying:

```
2018-07-16 14:25:28.355 DEBUG 8792 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9a00c039: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
...
2018-07-16 14:25:28.377 DEBUG 8792 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
```

Comment: Typically, when doing basic auth via header, the `user:password` is base64 encoded before sending

Comment: like `'Authorization': btoa('user:password')`?

Comment: Exactly. It's often prefixed with the word "Basic" as well, so the actual value should be something like `"Basic " + btoa('user:password')`

Comment: First of all, thx for your help. I just did: `'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('user:password')`, but I still don't see my header. The log is still: Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization

Comment: Any luck? Is that now working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, I must thank [user184994](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2780943/user184994) for his useful comment: adding `'Basic ' + btoa(...)` was indeed useful!

```
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('user:password')
```

Next, after testing with various browsers, I eventually stumbled into the following error message:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/resource: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.
```

After some research and much fiddling I found that adding CORS configuration to Spring Security did the trick.

```
http
     ...
     .and()
     .cors()
```